# How to speed up macro for large data?

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my code which gets called from sub Userfrom_Initialize. It's working perfectly. But when it comes to large no. of data it takes too long to display the form with loaded data. Can someone please help me?

```
Sub LoadData()
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim sqlstr As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim rn As Range
    Set rn = ActiveCell

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open "connection; "

    If rn.Offset(0, -1).Value = "abc" Then
        OptionButton2.Visible = False
        TextBox3.Visible = False


        sqlstr = "query"
        OptionButton1.Value = True
        TextBox1.Value = ActiveCell.Value

        rs.Open sqlstr, cn, adOpenStatic
        While Not rs.EOF
            ListBox1.AddItem rs(0).Value
            rs.MoveNext
        Wend
    End If

    If rn.Offset(0, -1).Value = "xyz" Then
        OptionButton1.Visible = False
        TextBox1.Visible = False

        sqlstr = "query"
        OptionButton2.Value = True
        TextBox3.Value = ActiveCell.Value

        rs.Open sqlstr, cn, adOpenStatic
        While Not rs.EOF
            ListBox1.AddItem rs(0).Value
            rs.MoveNext
        Wend
    End If


    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You are not at all clear where the slowdown is. There are two loops: is it one or both? Is it the SQL that is slow? How you define 'slow'? It is seconds, minutes? What profiling have you performed?

Comment: It could help that you use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51030734/6600940) approach to fill the listbox

Comment: No the query isnt slow,I checked. I am not able to figure out whats wrong that is why I posted.

Comment: You did not even try, did you? You will get rid of the loop `While Not rs.EOF
 ListBox1.AddItem rs(0).Value
 rs.MoveNext
 Wend`

Comment: @Storax - I tried, but still it is taking very long

Comment: Please show what you tried.

Comment: And how many reocrds do you load into the listbox?

Comment: 'arr = rs.GetRows
.List = arr'  I put this in while loop

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned your code a little bit and removed the `While Not rs.EOF ListBox1.AddItem rs(0).Value rs.MoveNext Wend` loops

```
Sub LoadData()
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim sqlstr As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim rn As Range
    Set rn = ActiveCell


    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False   ' <== not necessary

    cn.Open "connection; "

    sqlstr = "query"
    rs.Open sqlstr, cn, adOpenForwardOnly 

    Dim v As Variant
    v = rs.GetRows(, , rs.Fields(0).Name)


    If rn.Offset(0, -1).Value = "abc" Then
        OptionButton2.Visible = False
        TextBox3.Visible = False
        OptionButton1.Value = True
        TextBox1.Value = ActiveCell.Value

        ListBox1.Column = v
    End If

    If rn.Offset(0, -1).Value = "xyz" Then
        OptionButton1.Visible = False
        TextBox1.Visible = False
        OptionButton2.Value = True
        TextBox3.Value = ActiveCell.Value

        ListBox1.Column = v
    End If


    rs.Close  ' This will crash in the OP's version
    ' Set rs = Nothing  ' This is not neccessary
    cn.Close
    ' Set cn = Nothing  ' not neccessary
    ' Application.ScreenUpdating = True '  <== also not necessary

End Sub
```

**Update**: It seems that using [adOpenForwardOnly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/cursortype-property-ado?view=sql-server-ver15) solved the OP's issue

Comment: Still not working out for me. And Im trying to load around 4000 records in to the listbox.

Comment: I'd suggest top step through the Code and Identitfy the Line which takes long.

Comment: Im still not able to solve my issue. Can you please help me?

Comment: Where did it take long when you [stepped through](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html) the code?

Comment: Right now, without information from you please try to use `adOpenForwardOnly` instead of `adOpenStatic` although I do not really expect much improvement because of that change. I tried it with a bit more than 4.000 recorde. No performance issue at all. What else do you have on that userform? What else do you load?

Comment: Using adOpenForwardOnly worked perfectly for me. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Exclellent, I changed my answer accordingly